# Can someone explain to me to find the disk of convergence of the Taylor Series $\frac{3}{1+z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence

Can someone explain to me to find the disk of convergence of the Taylor Series for $\frac{3}{1+z}$.

I already found the Taylor series: $\frac{3}{2}[1-\frac{(z-1)}{2}+\frac{(z-1)}{2}^2-\frac{(z-1)}{2}^3...]$

Comment: Hint: What calculation will tell you the radius of convergence for a power series?

Comment: It's a geometric series which converges if the absolute value of the ratio is less than 1. What is the ratio in your example? Hint: $\dfrac{3}{1+z} = \dfrac{3}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1- -(\frac{z-1}{2})}$

Comment: Hint: a geometric series converges when its common ratio is less than $1$ (absolute).

Comment: Would the ratio be $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: No, the ratio is $-\left(\dfrac{z-1}{2}\right)$. You need to solve for which $z$-values make $\left|-\left(\dfrac{z-1}{2}\right)\right|$ less than $1$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So would the disk of convergence be $-1<z<3$?

Comment: You're working in the complex plane right? Then no, because you have treated the absolute value as absolute value of real numbers. The disk of convergence will be $|z-1| < 2$. This is an open disk centered at 1 with radius 2.

Comment: Yes, I am. How did you eliminate the negative sign without moving it to the other side and flipping the sign?

Comment: $|-f(z)| = |f(z)|$. So the negative sign makes no difference inside of the absolute value.